# ms sql Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a section of code that I am rebuilding from an outdated/overloaded MS Access system in PHP/MS SQL ... when I add a "Having" statement that includes IIf clauses I get the ms sql Incorrect syntax near ')'. See below ...

```
    SELECT SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Proposal #], PD_Mill_Start.[Job Name], PD_Mill_Start.[Promised Date], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Departure Date], PD_Mill_Start.[Date Shipped], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Shipped Date], DD_Truck_Table.[Ready Weight], DD_Truck_Table.[Max Load Weight], PD_Delivery_Schedule.Driver, SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Order Value], SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Invoice Amount], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Delivery Sequence], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Delivery Date/Time], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Departure Time], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Special Delivery Inst], IIf([COD Over Ride]<0,0,IIf([COD Over Ride]=999,0,IIf([COD Over Ride]>0,[COD Over Ride],IIf([Terms] Like '%cod%',[Balance Due],0)))) AS [COD Due], OE_Order_Entry_Header.Terms
FROM ((SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2 INNER JOIN (PD_Mill_Start INNER JOIN PD_Delivery_Schedule ON PD_Mill_Start.[Order Number] = PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Order Number]) ON SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Proposal #] = PD_Mill_Start.[Order Number]) INNER JOIN DD_Truck_Table ON PD_Delivery_Schedule.Truck = DD_Truck_Table.Truck) INNER JOIN OE_Order_Entry_Header ON SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Proposal #] = OE_Order_Entry_Header.[Order Header]
GROUP BY SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Proposal #], PD_Mill_Start.[Job Name], PD_Mill_Start.[Promised Date], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Departure Date], PD_Mill_Start.[Date Shipped], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Shipped Date], DD_Truck_Table.[Ready Weight], DD_Truck_Table.[Max Load Weight], PD_Delivery_Schedule.Driver, SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Order Value], SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Invoice Amount], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Delivery Sequence], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Delivery Date/Time], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Departure Time], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Special Delivery Inst], IIf([COD Over Ride]<0,0,IIf([COD Over Ride]=999,0,IIf([COD Over Ride]>0,[COD Over Ride],IIf([Terms] Like '%cod%',[Balance Due],0)))), OE_Order_Entry_Header.Terms
HAVING (((IIf([Date Shipped] Is Not Null,[Date Shipped],IIf([PD_Delivery_Schedule].[Departure Date] Is Not Null,[PD_Delivery_Schedule].[Departure Date],IIf([PD_Mill_Start].[Promised Date] Is Not Null,[PD_Mill_Start].[Promised Date]))))='9/7/2015'))
ORDER BY SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Proposal #] DESC;
```

If I remove the "HAVING" line and replace it with a simple X='9/3/2015' the script runs without errors but I need to be able to run the full set of IIf clauses.

Comment: How about making it readable, which would instantly highlight the unwanted bracket.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?   IIF is only valid in 2012 and higher.

Comment: Counting up the open `(` (5), you close one more `)` than was ever opened (6) in the `HAVING`.

Comment: What version of SQL server do you have? [IIF()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) is only available for 2012 and onwards. Otherwise, use `CASE/WHEN`.

Comment: Using SQL 2012 and Adam Martin answered the question, sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your innermost iif is missing an output for the false case.

`IIf([PD_Mill_Start].[Promised Date] Is Not Null,[PD_Mill_Start].[Promised Date]*,MISSING*)`

Comment: Thank you Adam ... figured it had to be something missing but my eyes were bugging out from converting all of the code from Access to PHP/SQL.

Comment: No problem!  If that fixes everything, you should accept the answer to close off the question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your GROUP BY and Having clause is valid but I have fixed your join issues.

```
SELECT 
        SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Proposal #]
      , PD_Mill_Start.[Job Name]
      , PD_Mill_Start.[Promised Date]
      , PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Departure Date]
      , PD_Mill_Start.[Date Shipped]
      , PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Shipped Date]
      , DD_Truck_Table.[Ready Weight]
      , DD_Truck_Table.[Max Load Weight]
      , PD_Delivery_Schedule.Driver
      , SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Order Value]
      , SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Invoice Amount]
      , PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Delivery Sequence]
      , PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Delivery Date/Time]
      , PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Departure Time]
      , PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Special Delivery Inst]
      , IIf([COD Over Ride]<0,0,
            IIf([COD Over Ride]=999,0,
                IIf([COD Over Ride]>0,[COD Over Ride],
                  IIf([Terms] Like '%cod%',[Balance Due],0)))) AS [COD Due]
      , OE_Order_Entry_Header.Terms
FROM        SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2 
INNER JOIN  PD_Mill_Start             ON SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Proposal #] = PD_Mill_Start.[Order Number]
INNER JOIN  PD_Delivery_Schedule      ON PD_Mill_Start.[Order Number] = PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Order Number]
INNER JOIN  DD_Truck_Table            ON PD_Delivery_Schedule.Truck = DD_Truck_Table.Truck) 
INNER JOIN  OE_Order_Entry_Header     ON SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Proposal #] = OE_Order_Entry_Header.[Order Header]
GROUP BY SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Proposal #], PD_Mill_Start.[Job Name], PD_Mill_Start.[Promised Date]
    , PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Departure Date], PD_Mill_Start.[Date Shipped], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Shipped Date]
    , DD_Truck_Table.[Ready Weight], DD_Truck_Table.[Max Load Weight], PD_Delivery_Schedule.Driver
    , SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Order Value], SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Invoice Amount], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Delivery Sequence]
    , PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Delivery Date/Time], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Departure Time], PD_Delivery_Schedule.[Special Delivery Inst]
    , IIf([COD Over Ride]<0,0,IIf([COD Over Ride]=999,0,IIf([COD Over Ride]>0,[COD Over Ride],IIf([Terms] Like '%cod%',[Balance Due],0)))), OE_Order_Entry_Header.Terms
HAVING (((IIf([Date Shipped] Is Not Null,[Date Shipped],IIf([PD_Delivery_Schedule].[Departure Date] Is Not Null,[PD_Delivery_Schedule].[Departure Date],IIf([PD_Mill_Start].[Promised Date] Is Not Null,[PD_Mill_Start].[Promised Date]))))='9/7/2015'))
ORDER BY SDS_MSTR_Order_Value_2.[Proposal #] DESC;
```